# SQL Server: Query Temporary Tables in new query windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp

I create a temp table with the following scripts

```
SELECT *
INTO #TEMP
FROM [mySchema].[Mytable]
```

The temp table location is at System Databases>Tempdp>temporary table>dbo.#Temp

How can I query the temp table in SQL Server New Query Windows from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) (V18.9.2)

Based on Zaynul Abadin Tuhin Answer: We can query the global temp table by creating ##Temp

SELECT *

INTO ##TEMP

FROM [mySchema].[Mytable]

Comment: You can't. Temporary tables are only accessible in the connection that created them.

Comment: make it global using double ##

Answer (score 3):

As already noted, a temporary table created with the single hash/pound `#` prefix is visible *only* to the connection that created it.

However, there's nothing stopping you from creating a normal user table in *tempDB* and benefitting from the various optimisations that exist for TempDB.

Of course any table you create you'll need to manage/remove yourself, it won't be automatically removed like a `#table` would be, but as it's a normal table any connection can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary table is just visible to session that created the temporary table.[msdn reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables)

> Temporary Tables
> You can create local and global temporary tables.
> Local temporary tables are visible only in the current session, and global temporary tables are visible to all sessions.

New Query Window is a new session, so it cannot refer to the temporary table created in another session.